# R: Add column with what number of appearance of x the current row is

Tags: r

(Probably answered before but can't find it probably wording it wrong.)

Have a current dataset and where each row is a different video entry but the same videos appear over and over again.

Need every time video_id(character) of the same video appears it says what number of appearance this is.
Example: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brpNS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(video_id=c('abc', rep('def', 2), rep('abc', 2), 'ghi', 'abc'), 
                 views=c(100, 50, 70, 120, 150, 300, 150))

df$appearance <- ave(df$views, df$video_id, FUN=seq_along)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly exactly want I needed!